# how to use stack or queue as datatype or use it in a column in SQL server

Tags: database-design, data-modeling, sql-server-2016

I created a table

```
tbl_order 
(orderID(pk) ,orderedItems , date , customerID(Fk))
```

and

```
tbl_foods 
(foodID(PK),foodname)
```

I want to store food IDs in orderedItems column

example in

```
tbl_Order

(orderID=1 , orderedItems(stack(1,4,5,7)), .... ) 1 ROW in tbl_Order
```

is it possible to do this in SQL server?

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Should you? No. Don't store delimited items in your data engine.

Comment: any better way ?? ... I think It reduces the relations @Larnu

Comment: if I don't  do that  I should add 2  more table  @Larnu

Comment: I assume you mean because there's a many to many relationship, you need 2 more tables? Yes, that would be correct.

Comment: how to implement stack or queue for each row as I asked earlier?  @Larnu

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: @Larnu     version  2016

Comment: Ok, edit that to your question (using tags), so that others can see what version you have. This means they know you can't use `STRING_AGG`. Then, hopefully, someone will be happy to tell you; i'm however, against giving you an answer on how to store delimited data in your data engine; especially as you seem against using normalised data.

Comment: ok tnx for your help @Larnu

Comment: Read about **normalization**, and the different normal forms. If you don't normalize your data, you'll spend far more time and computing cost in working with it, than in storage cost for the extra space needed. Take @Larnu advice here, and you'll also have to ask a lot fewer follow on questions on SO

Comment: One other thing to bear in mind, @SaeedAreffard - SQL Server is set-based rather than row-based, so it doesn't lend itself to queues or stacks or other RBAR structures/techniques.  Why do you want to create a queue or stack in this case?  *(RBAR - Row By Agonizing Row)

Comment: @scsimon Ok thanks for your advice

Comment: @Brian I wanted To use Stack for one column of each row ... then pop them in the asp.net form

Comment: 1 column or 100, it doesn't matter; it's not the right answer. If you want to use your data in a delimited format after, that's fine, but don't store it in such a manner. Having a couple of extra tables with a proper normalised relationship is the right answer everytime over using a delimited list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but it's so bad an idea that you need a new word for "bad".  I recommend an approach like this:

```
Customer
    ID
    Name
    etc.

Food
    ID
    Name
    Description
    etc.

Order
    ID
    Date
    CustomerID

OrderItem
    ID
    OrderID
    FoodID
```

Note: in each table, "ID" is the primary key, and "table-nameID" is a foreign key into "table-name".

The "queue" and "stack" behavior goes in your front-end code - concepts like that hardly ever have a place in an RDBMS.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks all ...I will use normalized one